Why does calloc allocate a new chunk instead of reusing tcache memory?
Let’s consider the following C code:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
        void *ptr;
        ptr = malloc(8);
        printf("First malloc: %p\n", ptr);
        free(ptr);

        ptr = malloc(8);
        printf("Second malloc: %p\n", ptr);
        free(ptr);

        ptr = calloc(1, 8);
        printf("Using calloc: %p\n", ptr);
        free(ptr);

        return 0;
}

This code allocates and frees 8 bytes on the heap three times in a row. When I execute this code, I get the following output:
First malloc: 0x560cceb282a0
Second malloc: 0x560cceb282a0
Using calloc: 0x560cceb286d0

We can see that the address is the same for the first and the second malloc, but the address is different for the calloc call.
To investigate further, I used GDB (with GEF) to see what happens:
gef➤  b 10
gef➤  r
gef➤  heap bins
─ Tcachebins for thread 1 ─
Tcachebins[idx=0, size=0x20] count=1  ←  Chunk(addr=0x5555555592a0, size=0x20, flags=PREV_INUSE) 

We can see that there is a chunk of size 0x20 in the tcache bins. This chunk should be reused for the next allocation of the same size. We can verify this after the second malloc:
gef➤  n
gef➤  heap bins
─ Tcachebins for thread 1 ─
All tcachebins are empty
gef➤  p ptr
$1 = (void *) 0x5555555592a0

Here, malloc reuses the chunk in the tcache bins, as expected. I would assume the same behavior for the next allocation (using calloc). Indeed, after the second free, the chunk is back in the tcache bins:
gef➤  n
gef➤  n
gef➤  heap bins
─ Tcachebins for thread 1 ─
Tcachebins[idx=0, size=0x20] count=1  ←  Chunk(addr=0x5555555592a0, size=0x20, flags=PREV_INUSE) 

However, after the next allocation, the tcache bins have not been used:
gef➤  n
gef➤  heap bins
─ Tcachebins for thread 1 ─
Tcachebins[idx=0, size=0x20] count=1  ←  Chunk(addr=0x5555555592a0, size=0x20, flags=PREV_INUSE) 
gef➤  p ptr
$2 = (void *) 0x5555555596d0

Why did the call to calloc not use the tcache bins?

Here is my build command, the version of gcc and the version of libc:
$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.2) 9.4.0
$ gcc -o exe src.c -g
$ ldd --version
ldd (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.31-0ubuntu9.16) 2.31

I am using Linux:
$ uname -a
Linux pierre-laptop 5.15.0-124-generic #134~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 1 15:27:33 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux


The source code for malloc and calloc should be available for you to read. What OS and compiler are you using?

@Someprogrammerdude I am using gcc on Ubuntu. I added this information at the end of my question.

Just a guess, but calloc might prefer to use fresh memory, so it doesn't have to clear it.

With MSVC all the pointers have the same value.

https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=25183

You are asking about behavior specific to a particular allocator implementation, and observing it in part with tools specific to that implementation. There is no answer at the high level at which the question is posed, and in fact, at that level the question is based on a false premise.  Furthermore, it being an implementation-specific detail that you seem to want to ask about, you're unlikely to get an authoritative answer any more specific than "that's the way it was implemented".

That's the way it was implemented.
